# Nginx reverse proxy to another nginx server serving static files

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have an Nginx server hosting a web app which works fine when directly accessed. Its config is below

```
server {
    listen 8000 default_server;

    listen [::]:8000 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /data/www/ ;
    server_name server1.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /app/ {

    }   
}
```

Now i have to serve this app from another Nginx server So i setup the reverse proxy like below

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /data/www/ ;
    server_name server2.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /app/ {
        proxy_pass http://server1.com:8000/app/;
    }
}
```

When i access the app from server2 i am getting errors like below for example when i am accessing http: server2.com/app/css/app.css

> [error] 6601#0: *1 open() "/data/www/app/css/app.css" failed (2: No such file or directory)

and no errors in serv er1 logs. Why is nginx looking for static files in server2 when i have set it to reverse proxy to server1 same setup works fine in apache with

> ProxyPass /app/ http:server1:8000/app/
>
> ProxyPassReverse /app/ http:server1:8000/app/

What am i missing ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, you didn't post full config. Provide full config of server2

Comment: Nothing else apart from browser caching like         location ~*  \.(css|js)$ {
          expires 365d;
        }

Comment: Exactly this location matches your `/app/css/app.css` and prevent proxing to server1

Comment: thanks alexey that was the problem plz post it as an answer i ll accept it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have regexp `location` that matches your request `/app/css/app.css` and intercepts request from proxy. That's how regexp `location`s works. To prevent this use `^~` modifier for your app location:

```
location ^~ /app/ {
    proxy_pass ...;
}
```

This will prevent regexp `location` from matching.

Documentation: http://nginx.org/r/location